# How to use .dll in Java

Tags: java, c#, dll

I have some C# code that I have compiled into a .dll to use as a resource for other programs.  How do I import that into my Java project for use and then how do you reference the code in the dll. I am using Eclispe for Java.

Comment: @JohnD that I read...I was looking at that but didn't really get it so that is why I asked this question

Comment: "didn't really get it" I don't really think you're going to have much success with this task, what you're trying to do is not well supported and more advanced. I would evaluate other options.

Comment: @JohnD what other options would there be that let me use C# in Java.  Converting the code is not an option.

Comment: I meant options other than using your C# code in Java.

Comment: @JohnD that isn't an option either.  Do you have any other ideas on how I can do this then?

Answer (score -1):

IMHO simplest way is to use JNA (Java Native Access) library, which simplify the process.
First, download jna.jar (https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar) and attach it to your project.

Later, create a interface in Java which will be bridge between your .dll library and java code in the following manner:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;


public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary(
        (Platform.isWindows() ? "windowsDLLName" : "otherDLLName"), CLibrary.class);
    void someMethof(String format, Object... args); // <--example function from dll lib
}
```

and later use it from java code calling f.e.

```
  CLibrary.INSTANCE.someMethod()
```

There is some topics you must cover:

native dll library access by JVM, see https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md

types mapping between Java and C/C++, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access
If you need examples, here are some sources :

https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access

blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/

Comment: Please see this meta discussion about why answers that are basically just links aren't really acceptable: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @Grzesuav But what if this isn't going to be native windows program?  In the code it says ifWindows() so does that mean that that would only work for windows? Is there a universal way to do that part?

Comment: There is no "universal" path because native programs required to be compiled separately per platform, f.e. on linux you don't have dll libraries, so you need to compile your native program also as linux *.so library. What exactly you meant to achieve ? I thought that the problem was calling native code from java. If you deal with native code, you are platform specific.